# Problems with particle hair in 2.72 (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, physics

So I made some hair in blender using cycles and as soon as i hit animate (the play button in the time line) it strongly resembles her standing in a pool of water with a live overhead powerline in it.

Obviously I am missing a setting here some place.

(video included.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3fG4QBpNTE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I've tried playing with all sorts of settings. and also set up a hair on another model using the same settings and it all behaves as it should.  I'm lost! this is going to be one of my main characters so I would really like to get this fixed.

Comment: put the subdivision modifier under the particle system

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same problem. Here is my example:

[image]

In my case I set up the hair settings, and then realized that the mesh isn't perfect. Then I tried to remove doubles, and change the geometry. 
Every time you change geometry (actions like: deleting, separating, ripping vertices) with the hair settings set up, you may see this problem appear.

My advice is to (before setting up the hair):

1. Apply rotation, location and scale. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Remove doubles.
3. Apply mirror modifier.
4. Recalculate normals. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>
5. Check the mesh using *"mesh lint addon"* and make sure the mesh is 'clear' (has no ngons and interior faces).

After applying all the things mentioned above my problem was solved.