# rigged character's hair/particle system doesn't follow the movements

Tags: rigging, armature, particles

I created a simple male base mesh and put some fur and hair on him. However, whenever I rig the character and try to pose him the fur doesn't move along with the body, which confusing me.
Here is my **[blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/157/)**.

Answer (score 8):

The problem may be with the modifiers order. Make sure that in the *'object modifiers panel'* your **Particle Systems are below the Armature**. See the printscreen below:
[image]

I checked your model and I think it demands a little clean up:). You should remove doubles before adding a hair. If you don't you may expect a strange hair behavior on your model. Please check out this topic:
[Problems with particle hair in 2.72 (cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16489/problems-with-particle-hair-in-2-72-cycles).

Comment: Also make sure that *use modifier stack* is checked in the particle settings.